# asp.net delete various textboxes at once with vb loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, controls

In an asp.net webpage I have about 35 textboxes below a gridview, which get populated as you click each of the rows in the gridview.

All works fine, however I would like to clear all fields quickly before populating again.

The fields id are all like these:

txtO1_C

txtO2_C

txtO3_C

txtO4_C

etc...

So I would like to know if there is a possibility in vb to do something like in VBA:

```
for l=1 to 20
    frmName.Controls("txtO" & l & "_C").Caption = vbnullstring
next l
```

I am trying to avoid having to do a  `txtOX_C.Text =""` for each individual textbox if there is faster way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this but first you have to find the control in which textboxes are placed.If they are directly in page than this code will work

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList<TextBox>().ForEach(a => a.Text = "");
```

If textboxes are inside another control first you will have to find that control

```
 Control ctrl = this.FindControl("controlid");
 ctrl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList<TextBox>().ForEach(a => a.Text = "");
```

And if you want to set text of textboxes which contains some specific string than you may try this

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(a=>a.ID.Contains("txt")).ToList<TextBox>().ForEach(a => a.Text = "Mairaj");
```

This is C# code you can convert this to its equivalent VB code.

Comment: is this vb ? The code I am after is like the one on your last example, however when pasting it to the aspx.vb page, it gives several errors (this., <TextBox>, a => a gets errors)

Comment: Sorry this is c# you can convert it to vb.

Comment: I thought so, I did convert it however I do get an error when running. This is the code...the (Of textbox) is where the error is...

Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(a) a.ID.Contains("txt")).ToList(Of TextBox)().ForEach(Function(a) InlineAssignHelper(a.Text, "Mairaj"))

Comment: I just wanted to give u solution so you can apply it in VB.net

Comment: I understand. Your code did put me in the right direction and after further checking I was able to do what I was looking for.